# IE display problem

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a page, and I just added pagination to it, but there's a prob in IE 7 & 8.
When I add pagination code

```
echo "<div class='pagination'>";
echo $pagination->GetPageLinks();
echo "</div>";
```

it breaks somehow layout in IE, I have looked all over it and I couldn't find what's wrong there.
oh, and its css

```
div.pagination {
    text-align : center;
}

div.pagination a, div.pagination span {
    padding : 5px;
    display : inline-block;
}
```

page url - [adelija.puslapiai.lt](http://adelija.puslapiai.lt), it's on index page, if you could take a look, that'd be great.

This is how it looks in IE8 - http://i47.tinypic.com/b8vmoi.jpg
FF - http://i46.tinypic.com/rssxds.jpg

Comment: Could you post a screenshot somewhere? Perhaps just by looking at that and the source, someone could determine the issue. Just from looking at the source above—though I could be wrong—I'm guessing it has to do with `inline-block`.

Comment: Ok, I updated the post with pics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if this will fix it, but you have an unclosed span tag here:

```
<div class='pagination'><span>1</span><span>|</span><a href="/index.php?page=2">2</a><span>|</span><a href="/index.php?page=3">3</a><span>|</span</div>         <!-- End .post -->

    </div>
```

If that doesn't work to fix it, you might try clearing the float in `.pagination` as it looks to me like everything is floated left and cleared by the footer. Something in your pagination code is preventing the footer from clearing your wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

The last span is unclosed (About line 55)
just close it correctly (Replace `</span with </span>)` and that should do the job

Comment: Yes, this worked, I just didn't see what was wrong with my code :| Thank you!